# Observable.interval not working when the app is in the background

Tags: rx-java2

Using rxjava2 (2.1.8) Observable.interval to invoke a RESTful API every 13 minutes. Its working fine if the app is running in the foreground and not working when the app is in the background. I am unable to post the entire code code due to restrictions.

```
Observable.interval(13, TimeUnit.Milliseconds)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(...
```

Really appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Maybe you're disposing the "disposable" object returned by the subscribe method?

Answer (score 0):

For long running operation your code should be executed in a `Service`. There are though some [limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), introduced with Android 8, that you may want to check.

However, you can schedule your task using an `AmarmManager` or a better alternative: `[JobScheduler][2]`. With the JobScheduler you can also define the criteria that need to be met for executing your tasks.

**NOTE**: 
`.interval(13, TimeUnit.Milliseconds)` means one item emitted every 13 milliseconds, not minutes!